# Overloading Method with dynamic and other types

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, overloading

Why I cant overload Method with `dynamic` and `object` Parameters.

```
void Method(dynamic arg) // Member with same signature is already declared
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dynamic");
}
void Method(object arg) // Member with same signature is already declared
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Dynamic");
}
```

But I can overload Method with `dynamic` and another type **except** object or dynamic it self.

```
void Method(dynamic arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dynamic");
}
void Method(string arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Dynamic");
}
```

As you can see in the first example compiler can't discriminate two overloads.

I think the second example should not work too because string can be send to both overloads. However Compiler Prefers to call the overload with known type.

I've done some test to see how actually it works.

```
Method("");          // Prints: Not Dynamic
Method((dynamic)""); // Prints: Not Dynamic
Method(null);        // Prints: Not Dynamic
Method(???);         // Dynamic for any other type except string and null.
```

Consider first example works and compiler would decide like this:

```
Method(new object());// Prints: Not Dynamic
Method((object)5);   // Prints: Not Dynamic
Method(???);          // Prints: Dynamic for any other type except object and null.
```

So where is the confusion to the compiler? Why I cant have such overloads?

Comment: Default type of dynamic is `object`. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx))

Comment: thanks.this make sense now. i thought we have type of dynamic. but actually we dont. thats why i cant use `typeof(dynamic)` and the Default type is object. the answer. @AVD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C# 5.0 specification, *4.7 The dynamic type*:

> The type dynamic has special meaning in C#. Its purpose is to allow dynamic binding, which is described in detail in §7.2.2.
>   dynamic **is considered identical to object** except in the following respects:
>   
> •  Operations on expressions of type dynamic can be dynamically bound (§7.2.2).
>   
> •  Type inference (§7.5.2) will prefer dynamic over object if both are candidates.
>   
> Because of this equivalence, the following holds:
>   
> •  There is an implicit identity conversion between object and dynamic, and between constructed types that are the same when replacing dynamic with object
>   
> •  Implicit and explicit conversions to and from object also apply to and from dynamic.
>   
> •  **Method signatures that are the same when replacing dynamic with object are considered the same signature**

In fact, once your code is compiled, a method having `dynamic` as a parameter is effectively the same as if that same method were declared using `object`. It's simply that inside the method, the `dynamic` parameter can be used dynamically (i.e. with run-time binding).

Because of this, your first example pair of methods is essentially the same as if you'd declared both methods with the parameter type of `object`.

In your second example, just as you can have overloads where one has a parameter of `object` and the other a parameter of `string`, so too can you pair a method using `dynamic` with a method of the same name using `string`.

Per the overload resolution rules for C# (also in the specification), as long as the method parameter lists are different in ways that allow one method overload to be chosen as the "best" overload, no compile-time error will occur. In your specific example, passing anything other than a `string` to the method automatically excludes the method with `string` as a parameter. In the case where you do pass `string`, the overload resolution rules select the `string` overload as the "best" overload, so no compile error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. specially the part that overload resolution chooses the best overload. was really helpful.