# Method overloading with dynamic data types

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dynamic, overloading

Why compiler is restraining to overload method in below way, Compilation Error i get in update method with dynamic type parameter.

Error - Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'update' with the same parameter types

```
static void update(string name)
    {

    }
static void update(object name)
    {

    }

static void update(dynamic name)
    {

    }
```

Comment: the thing is: `dynamic` could be _anything_. including a `string` or an `object`. so, when using `dynamic`, how should the compiler determine _which_ overload to use?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374650/overloading-method-with-dynamic-and-other-types) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overloading Method with dynamic and other types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374650/overloading-method-with-dynamic-and-other-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `dynamic` is also a type of `object`. You can check the generated IL code. So its giving compilation error for

```
static void update(object name)
    {

    }

static void update(dynamic name)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `dynamic` parameter type, i.e.

```
static void update(dynamic name)
{
}
```

compiler changes the signature of your method to use `object` instead, i.e.

```
static void update(object name)
{
}
```

and then inserts some "magic" in the body of your method in order to treat `name` as a dynamically-typed object. This, however, introduces an important limitation: you cannot have another method `update` that takes `object`, because you already have one.

Think about this overload from the perspective of language designer: when you see a call to an overload between `object` and `dynamic`, there would be no intuitively understood way to resolve the tie, because both `object` and `dynamic` could accommodate objects of any type. Hence, overloads like this should be disallowed anyway, regardless of the underlying implementation for `dynamic`.